# How to get cropped image after crop as a form data in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import ReactCrop from 'react-image-crop';
import 'react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.css';

class CoachDashboard extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    src: null,
    crop: {
      unit: '%',
      width: 50,
      aspect: 20 / 16,
    },
  };

  onSelectFile = e => {
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener('load', () =>
        this.setState({ src: reader.result })
      );
      reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
      console.log(e.target.files[0])
    }
  };

  onImageLoaded = image => {
    this.imageRef = image;
  };

  onCropComplete = crop => {
    this.makeClientCrop(crop);
  };

  onCropChange = (crop, percentCrop) => {
    this.setState({ crop });
  };

  async makeClientCrop(crop) {
    if (this.imageRef && crop.width && crop.height) {
      const croppedImageUrl = await this.getCroppedImg(
        this.imageRef,
        crop,
        'newFile.jpeg'
      );
      console.log(croppedImageUrl)
      this.setState({ croppedImageUrl });
    }
  }

  getCroppedImg(image, crop, fileName) {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const scaleX = image.naturalWidth / image.width;
    const scaleY = image.naturalHeight / image.height;
    canvas.width = crop.width;
    canvas.height = crop.height;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  ctx.drawImage(
      image,
      crop.x * scaleX,
      crop.y * scaleY,
      crop.width * scaleX,
      crop.height * scaleY,
      0,
      0,
      crop.width,
      crop.height
    );

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      canvas.toBlob(blob => {
        if (!blob) {
          console.error('Canvas is empty');
          return;
        }
        blob.name = fileName;
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.fileUrl);
        this.fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        resolve(this.fileUrl);
      }, 'image/jpeg');
    });
  }




  render() {
    const { crop, croppedImageUrl, src } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <div>
          <input type="file" onChange={this.onSelectFile} />
        </div>
        <div style={{ width:'500px' }}>
        {src && (
          <ReactCrop
            src={src}
            crop={crop}
            ruleOfThirds
            onImageLoaded={this.onImageLoaded}
            onComplete={this.onCropComplete}
            onChange={this.onCropChange}
            width= '200'
            height= '200'
          />
        )}
        </div>
        {croppedImageUrl && (
          <img alt="Crop" style={{ height:'200px' }} src={croppedImageUrl} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default CoachDashboard;
```

Here i am cropping an image using `react-image-crop`.

I have to send that image file to backend and store to database.

But, in `onSelectChange()` function I am getting actual image file using `e.target.files[0]`.

But after cropping  when i am printing `croppedImageUrl` inside `makeClientCrop()` function I am getting one fake image url.

How can I get actual image file after cropping like I am getting in `onSelectChange()` function while `console.log()`?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do it is save the blob file inside the state in canvas.toBlob inside the getCroppedImg function and later convert it in a file when saving the file.

```
  getCroppedImg(image, crop, fileName) {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const scaleX = image.naturalWidth / image.width;
    const scaleY = image.naturalHeight / image.height;
    canvas.width = crop.width;
    canvas.height = crop.height;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  ctx.drawImage(
      image,
      crop.x * scaleX,
      crop.y * scaleY,
      crop.width * scaleX,
      crop.height * scaleY,
      0,
      0,
      crop.width,
      crop.height
    );

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      canvas.toBlob(blob => {
        if (!blob) {
          console.error('Canvas is empty');
          return;
        }
        blob.name = fileName;
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.fileUrl);
        this.fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        this.setState({blobFile:blob}) // Set blob image inside the state here 
        resolve(this.fileUrl);
      }, 'image/jpeg');
    });
  }

// To save file 
onFileSave(){
const {blobFile} = this.state;
const newImage = new File([blobFile], blobFile.name, { type: blobFile.type });
let fd = new FormData();
fd.append(newImage.name, newImage);
saveImageToServer(fd);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this came to my rescue big time! :))